# Cannot find GWT SDKs (Eclipse 4.3)

Tags: gwt, eclipse-plugin

I was trying to install Google Plugin for Eclipse 4.3 by the instructions listed below:

https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/install-eclipse-4.3

The problem I got is that I cannot find the "SDKs". It seems the GWT SDKs is not there for download.

Comment: Plugin is not same as the SDK. Plugin just makes it easy to work with GWT projects. SDK needs to be downloaded separately. Once you download and extract the SDK, you have to configure its location in Eclipse's Preferences. Have you downloaded the SDK?

Comment: @naXa Plugin does include the SDKs.

Comment: Did you try to create a GWT project?